# vCenter in nested ESXi kills the host vCenter session

Tags: networking, virtualization, vmware-esxi, vmware-esx, vmware-vcenter

I created a nested ESXi environment (virtualised ESXi host inside an ESXi. Lets name it vESXi for simplicity) for testing purposes. In the (nested)VM network I assigned the necessary attributes to VM-s and they can send packages amongst each other and ping the virtual host with reply. These VM-s cannot be accessed from outside networks. Till that point everything is fine.

But we needed a vCenter server on the top of that so I moved a copy of the host vCenter inside the vESXi and purged the old datastores, and resource pools and assigned the new ones. It works fine and doing its job. The IP address of the vCenter server is the same as on the original (I use the same private IP address spaces for convenience) and that's where the problem comes in.

When the nested vCenter is up and running and on a virtual VM network with 'physical' adapter assigned, sometimes kills the vCenter client session of the host ESXi. 
And my question is how is it possible if I can't reach the nested network at all? In my best knowledge the virtual VM network shouldn't interfere with the outside. Maybe I just miss something crucially simple?

Sorry if anything is unclear and if it is I'll try to explain it further and provide more information.

Comment: Obviously you need to use different IP address ranges.

Comment: I know that the problem comes from the same IP addresses but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to change the IP address of your nested vCenter server. You have an IP conflict on your network and the switches don't know which server to send the packets to.